# Flow Array type fails on subset of that type

Tags: flowtype

I have a function that is used in a lot of different places, so it has a very broad typing:

`export const stringToArrayFn = (
  accessor?:
    | Function
    | string
    | boolean
    | Object
    | Array<Function | string | boolean | Object>,
  defaultAccessor?: Function,
  raw?: boolean
)`

When I call it:

`stringToArrayFn(yAccessor)`

With yAccessor being typed as:

`yAccessor?: Array<Function | string> | Function | string`

Flow complains `Cannot call stringToArrayFn with yAccessor bound to accessor because boolean [1] is incompatible with
string [2] in array element.`

I don't get it because the Array in yAccessor is a valid subset of the array possibilities defined in stringToArrayFn (the former only allows arrays of function or string, the latter allows arrays of functions, strings, bools and objects).

How does one handle this kind of typing?

Comment: I wrote a question and answer about the same problem with the aim of explaining it better – not sure if it counts as a duplicate or not: [Flow doesn’t let me pass `Array<A>` to `Array<A | B>` (array of subtypes to array of supertypes)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51933973/578288)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stringToArrayFn` could call `accessor.push(true)` and cause your `Array<Function | string>` to contain a `boolean`, which would be bad.

Use `$ReadOnlyArray` instead of `Array` in the definition of `stringToArrayFn` if it doesn't intend to mutate the provided array.

Comment: Oh I see! Thanks so much.