# FlowType: Array is too strict about the generic parameter's shape

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Why flow is so strict about the shape of the array elements. When it is a single object it's cool with it, but array is somehow not happy. Is it possible to make it work somehow?

```
function foo1(x: { a: string, b: number }) {
  foo2(x) // all cool, no errors
}
function foo2(x: { a: string }) {
}

function foo3(x: Array<{ a: string, b: number }>) {
  foo4(x)  // error, see below
}
function foo4(x: Array<{ a: string }>) {
}
```

// Error message

```
foo4(x)
     ^ Cannot call `foo4` with `x` bound to `x` because property `b` is missing in object type [1] but exists in object type [2] in array element.
References:
12: function foo4(x: Array<{ a: string }>) {
                           ^ [1]
9: function foo3(x: Array<{ a: string, b: number }>) {
```

https://flow.org/try/#0PQKgBAAgZgNg9gdzCYAoVUCuA7AxgFwEs5swo44BGACgA8AuMAbzAENGBnfAJ0OwHMANGABGjbJgC2IgKbcwAXwCUzVGDIUATHSWoFGHAWKlycbQ2ZtOPPv0Uqme9FjxESGuAGY6jAILduVgBPAB4WdjAuXgFhMTAJaTlFAD4HNQ8AFh0nFyN3UyyLf0DQ8OtouwVU1QUgA

**EDIT:**

I found a way how to make it work by using $Subtype<>, but I still don't understand why the code above doesn't work, so answers welcome.

```
function foo3(x: Array<{ a: string, b: number }>) {
  foo4(x)
}

function foo4(x: Array<$Subtype<{ a: string }>>) {
}
```

Comment: You'll need to explicitly make `b` an optional property of the objects in the `foo4()` type declaration.

Comment: But what if I don't know which props can come in the array elements, I only care about one, is there something "unsafe" in it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51332802/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer is function `foo4` can modify the array and push `{ a: 'foo' }`, but it will violate the type of the original array which is `{ a: string, b: number }`.

So the proper solution would be to use

```
function foo4(x: $ReadOnlyArray<{ a: string }>) {
}
```

in this case `foo4` can't mutate the array so we are safe

Thanks [Ryan Cavanaugh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1704166/ryan-cavanaugh) for pointing to the answer in the comment to the question