# Flow doesn’t let me pass `Array<A>` to `Array<A | B>` (array of subtypes to array of supertypes)

Tags: javascript, arrays, flowtype

I have a value of type `Array<A>` (an array of subtypes). Flow doesn’t let me pass it to a place that expects `Array<A | B>` (an array of supertypes), even though it obviously works.

For example, I can’t assign a value with type `Array<'left' | 'right'>` to a variable whose type is `Array<string>`:

```js
const directions: Array<'left' | 'right'> = ['right', 'left'];
const messages: Array<string> = directions; // error
```

This error is raised:

```
2: const messages: Array<string> = directions; // error
                                   ^ Cannot assign `directions` to `messages` because in array element: Either string [1] is incompatible with string literal `left` [2]. Or string [1] is incompatible with string literal `right` [3].
    References:
    2: const messages: Array<string> = directions; // error
                             ^ [1]
    1: const directions: Array<'left' | 'right'> = ['right', 'left'];
                               ^ [2]
    1: const directions: Array<'left' | 'right'> = ['right', 'left'];
                                        ^ [3]
```

<sup>[Try Flow demo](https://flow.org/try/#0MYewdgzgLgBAJgSwE4FNhQeCAuGBBJJAQwE8AeAcgBsUAzKCmAHxgqQQHMALBgPhgC8MANptOPCgBpWNehQC6AbgBQoSLAC2KCBCIdtuAsXLR2YDvyGJU6TJEUwA9I5gpCIJEA)</sup>

Similarly, I can’t pass an `Array<ANode>` to a function that takes `Array<Node>`, even though `Node` is `ANode | BNode`:

```js
type ANode = {type: 'a', value: string};
type BNode = {type: 'b', count: number};

type Node = ANode | BNode;

function getFirstNodeType(nodes: Array<Node>): string {
    return nodes[0].type;
}

// works
const nodesSupertype: Array<Node> = [{type: 'a', value: 'foo'}];
getFirstNodeType(nodesSupertype);

// error
const nodesSubtype: Array<ANode> = [{type: 'a', value: 'foo'}];
getFirstNodeType(nodesSubtype); // error
```

```
16: getFirstNodeType(nodesSubtype); // error
                    ^ Cannot call `getFirstNodeType` with `nodesSubtype` bound to `nodes` because property `value` is missing in `BNode` [1] but exists in `ANode` [2] in array element.
References:
6: function getFirstNodeType(nodes: Array<Node>): string {
                                            ^ [1]
15: const nodesSubtype: Array<ANode> = [{type: 'a', value: 'foo'}];
                                ^ [2]

16: getFirstNodeType(nodesSubtype); // error
                    ^ Cannot call `getFirstNodeType` with `nodesSubtype` bound to `nodes` because string literal `a` [1] is incompatible with string literal `b` [2] in property `type` of array element.
References:
1: type ANode = {type: 'a', value: string};
                        ^ [1]
2: type BNode = {type: 'b', count: number};
                        ^ [2]
```

<sup>[Try Flow demo](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAggcgewCbQLxQN6kgLigcgEN8AaKAN0IBsBXCPAZ2ACcBLAOwHMBfAbgChs0AEKIUUdFnD0CAI1JQAxghrtgedjQC2siMz79B0qGLSxTUAD5RRyCAP4AzVYuCsE7KJwjAAYq2YmUwAVaQAKdjsGPBhmZkIQAB5TAD4ASkYWDk5Mfih8qGYfGmZPSJQGAG0ABgBdADohAW5DAHpWqAB3BGYAawZ+ZXYmKHKIBgBlGkhmIRi4hOS7FIkoSqlcAmIySloZfEcEBHxuWoFvPwCgu1DICKipmaE0h3aoPWYewY8RscmaWRzWALJLwZardZAogKXZ0PAHI4nM78C7+QLAELhP5TQHSF5QN4fHpAA)</sup>

Comment: This question is about the same problem as [Flow Array type fails on subset of that type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51332802/578288). I posted this question instead of adding a new answer on that question for two reasons: to provide better, simplified examples for people to understand the problem, and to mention different keywords for people searching about this issue. The first of those two reasons might suggest that this question shouldn’t be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Flow raises an error because it thinks you **might mutate the array**:

```js
// given the definitions of `Node`, `ANode`, and `BNode` from the question’s second example

function getFirstNodeType(nodes: Array<Node>): string {
    const bNode: BNode = {type: 'b', count: 0}
    // Mutate the parameter `nodes`. Adding a `BNode` is valid according its type.
    nodes.push(bNode);

    return nodes[0].type;
}

const nodesSubtype: Array<ANode> = [{type: 'a', value: 'foo'}];
getFirstNodeType(nodesSubtype); // error
```

<sup>[Try Flow demo](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAggcgewCbQLxQN6kgLigcgEN8AaKAN0IBsBXCPAZ2ACcBLAOwHMBfAbgChs0AEKIUUdFnD0CAI1JQAxghrtgedjQC2siMz79B0qGLSxTUAD5RRyCAP4AzVYuCsE7KJwjAAYq2YmUwAVaQAKdjsGPBhmZkIQAB5TAD4ASkYWDk5Mfih8pQ8mKFlTPFtxSSE8fHkyZVV1KAAGbjyCgHoOqABZGmBCYGhgAAtoMEJ4rR89KAADSJQGOYA6WCQkbKhCeYqIOahWBgpqViRtxWVmTa5D4GOhFfb8xYgGFbAaBhGw0rs0gQFKDPKDMHw0ZieV4MADazQAuishAI2vxlOxitCAMo0WTVWBxBKJeB2FISKAwqS4AjEMiUWgyfCOBAIfDceECbx+AJBOyhSARKI4vHSAFQLpQPTMBDMIA)</sup>

After running the above code, `nodesSubtype` would contain a `BNode` even though it is declared as an array of `ANode`, violating its type.

There are two solutions to convince Flow that you won’t mutate the array. The clearest one is to **replace `Array` with** the Flow utility type [**`$ReadOnlyArray`**](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/arrays/#toc-readonlyarray).

```js
function getFirstNodeType(nodes: $ReadOnlyArray<Node>): string { // use $ReadOnlyArray
    return nodes[0].type;
}

const nodesSubtype: Array<ANode> = [{type: 'a', value: 'foo'}];
getFirstNodeType(nodesSubtype); // no error
```

<sup>[Try Flow demo](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAggcgewCbQLxQN6kgLigcgEN8AaKAN0IBsBXCPAZ2ACcBLAOwHMBfAbgChs0AEKIUUdFnD0CAI1JQAxghrtgedjQC2siMz79B0qGLSxTUAD5RRyCAP4AzVYuCsE7KJwjAAYq2YmUwAVaQAKdjsGPAASACUIQiQAeXYqEBhmZkIQAB5TAD4ASkYWDk5MKAB6KqgaBmh4xJS0jKyc-iguqGYfGmZPSJQGAG0ABgBdADohAW5DZXYmKCGIBgBlGlkhPEzsvPg7AokoEalcAmIySloZfEcEBHxuCYFvPwCgu1DICKjN7bSIq8aq1SJQPTMBDMIA)</sup>

You only have to make that replacement in the function parameter’s type (e.g. `nodes`), but if you liked you could use `$ReadOnlyArray` everywhere it applies (e.g. for `nodesSubtype`).

`$ReadOnlyArray` is the most type-safe solution, but you may not want to have to change all your existing functions to use it. In that case, your alternative is to **cast the array type through `any`** instead. Yes, you could have done that from the beginning, but at least now you know *why* it’s safe to do this cast. You can even leave a comment explaining why this cast exists, which might help you catch assumptions no longer being valid.

```js
function getFirstNodeType(nodes: Array<Node>): string {
    return nodes[0].type;
}

const nodesSubtype: Array<ANode> = [{type: 'a', value: 'foo'}];
// casting `Array<ANode>` to `Array<Node>` is okay because we know that `getFirstNodeType` won’t actually modify the array
getFirstNodeType(((nodesSubtype: any): Array<Node>));
```

<sup>[Try Flow demo](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAggcgewCbQLxQN6kgLigcgEN8AaKAN0IBsBXCPAZ2ACcBLAOwHMBfAbgChs0AEKIUUdFnD0CAI1JQAxghrtgedjQC2siMz79B0qGLSxTUAD5RRyCAP4AzVYuCsE7KJwjAAYq2YmUwAVaQAKdjsGPBhmZkIQAB5TAD4ASkYWDk5Mfih8qGYfGmZPSJQGAG0ABgBdADohAW5DZXYmKHKIBgBlGlkhGLiExPg7FIkoSqlcAmIySloZfEcEBHxuWoEAem2lQiZsqAADWPiksZQU46hgBBOzkdSb1gYoBABrBKhdRUIaBjQADu0A+kSBtwAFoRgCdvH4AkE7KFIDcgR5AJgEsMIrho1CoICgWmQrEchOAkOghGGIH48P8gWAIXCYQiUT6A2keEI7BAGVgNOS4zSaV4QA)</sup>

If you don’t care about documenting the problem, you can omit the comment and only cast to `any`:

```js
getFirstNodeType((nodesSubtype: any));
```

<sup>[Try Flow demo](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAggcgewCbQLxQN6kgLigcgEN8AaKAN0IBsBXCPAZ2ACcBLAOwHMBfAbgChs0AEKIUUdFnD0CAI1JQAxghrtgedjQC2siMz79B0qGLSxTUAD5RRyCAP4AzVYuCsE7KJwjAAYq2YmUwAVaQAKdjsGPBhmZkIQAB5TAD4ASkYWDk5Mfih8qGYfGmZPSJQGAG0ABgBdADohAW5DZXYmKHKIBgBlGlkhGLiExPg7FIkoSqlcAmIySloZfEcEBHxuWoFvPwCgu1DIMIiovoHpPEJ2EDS03iA)</sup>

### Additional resources

- `$ReadOnlyArray` became [documented](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/arrays/#toc-readonlyarray) in August 2018, thanks to [this pull request](https://github.com/facebook/flow/pull/6595).
- The older article [“Flow’s best kept secret”](https://medium.com/@forbeslindesay/covariance-and-contravariance-c3b43d805611) describes a third possible workaround, involving wrapping the function’s array type in a generic type.